# Изминение ширины колонки для всех TreeViewItem в TreeView элементе

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: Property grid]

Это **TreeView**, пытаюсь сделать свой редактор свойств каждый **TreeViewItem** состоит из двух колонок. В одной колонке имя свойства, в другой само значение свойства. Так же к первой колонке прикреплён **GridSpilter**, который меняет её размер.
Вопрос такой, как можно сделать что бы при изминение ширины колонки в первом **TreeViewItem** приводила к изминению ширины первой колонки всех остольных **TreeViewItem**-ов?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

заведите отдельное свойство (например, в виде прикрепленного DependencyProperty) в TreeView и забиндите ширину колонки на это свойство. Тогда изменение ширины колонки  одного элемента будет приводить к изменению ширин всех элементов.

Comment: упс, точно, чёт я про **DependencyProperty** совсем забыл, щас сделаю :))